# PHP & JSON Decoding

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode some basic JSON data from Mintpal.com (https://www.mintpal.com/api)

The raw data looks like:

```
[
    {
        "market_id": "152",
        "coin": "VeriCoin",
        "code": "VRC",
        "exchange": "BTC",
        "last_price": "0.00008512",
        "yesterday_price": "0.00009300",
        "change": "-8.47",
        "24hhigh": "0.00009450",
        "24hlow": "0.00008050",
        "24hvol": "13.153",
        "top_bid": "0.00008063",
        "top_ask": "0.00008591"
    }
]
```

I just want to pull bits off this information out and assign them to variables. I use the below code with another near identical JSON output and it works fine.

```
//GET MINTPAL JSON DATA
$url = "https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/VRC/BTC";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($contents); 

//GET 'LAST BID' INFO
$lastBid = $json->code;
```

The previous raw JSON that works with the above code looks exactly the same, except for not being encased in '[...]' as the Mintpal one is.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "result": [
        {
            "MarketName": "BTC-LTC",
            "High": 0.01126000,
            "Low": 0.01060000,
            "Volume": 442.30927821,
            "Last": 0.01061100,
            "BaseVolume": 4.86528601,
            "TimeStamp": "2014-08-27T13:49:03.497",
            "Bid": 0.01051801,
            "Ask": 0.01061100,
            "OpenBuyOrders": 50,
            "OpenSellOrders": 116,
            "PrevDay": 0.01079000,
            "Created": "2014-02-13T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas on why I can't read the information this time round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you either did a `var_dump()` or a `print_r()` of your `$json` variable you should see that it is now an array starting at element 0 containing all the unique json elements.

```
//GET MINTPAL JSON DATA
$url = "https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/VRC/BTC";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($contents); 

pR($json);

//GET 'LAST BID' INFO
$lastBid = $json->code;

function pR($data){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

That yielded:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [market_id] => 152
            [coin] => VeriCoin
            [code] => VRC
            [exchange] => BTC
            [last_price] => 0.00008512
            [yesterday_price] => 0.00009300
            [change] => -8.47
            [24hhigh] => 0.00009300
            [24hlow] => 0.00008050
            [24hvol] => 12.968
            [top_bid] => 0.00008065
            [top_ask] => 0.00008585
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: For anyone else facing the issue, you can use my first code, just swap the $json->code line for: $lastBid = $json[0]->last_price;

Comment: Any time. This is why we're all here.